# Angular Oracle OAM integration

Tags: oracle, angular, single-sign-on

I need to implement a SPA application by using Anuglar. One of the requirement is the application must be authenticated via Oracle and get the user roles. I know how to do it in java web application, but new to angular. We are planning to use angular 2 for it. Please give me some advise.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I don't found any solution yet. However, I try to secure the SPA by webgate and I have to find the way make the angular to read the request header which is redirected by WebGate.